# How to Authorize APIGateway calls to a Lambda Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway which is connected to a Lambda Function. And In the Method Request for a particular POST Method, I want some restricted people only to be able to call the Method.

One way I can implement that is by explicitly passing a token in the request body which I can provide to every authenticated user and then checking if a token is present in the method. Also, I saw `Authorization : AWS_IAM` in the  Method Request details.

I am new to AWS and cannot figure out how to call the API with `AWS_IAM` authorization via an external Application using the URL we get after deploying the API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want some restricted people only to be able to call the Method

One way of doing this is by means of [API keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html):

> API keys are alphanumeric string values that you distribute to application developer customers to **grant access to your API**.

In your question you wrote about "explicitly passing a token in the request body" but it was not clear if you want to implement such a solution yourself, or use the solution provided by API Gateway (i.e. API keys)

The [IAM authentication for API Gateway APIs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/) will require to **create IAM group or IAM users** for those "restricted people" in your AWS Account. General steps for that are explained here:

- [Control access for invoking an API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html)
- [How do I enable IAM authentication for API Gateway APIs?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do this using the API Gateway Authorizers and create a Cognito Authorizer as you are already using a token of the Authenticated user you can achieve this by:

- Go to your API gateway select Authorizers from the left menu.
- Click on create Authorizer.
- After clicking create Authorizer you will have the below screen that will give you the ability to add your existing Cognito user pool and add "Authorization" as token source.

  [image: List item]

  - After setting up your Authorizer you will be able to use the "idToken" returned by Cognito after an authentication and pass it in your API request as Authorization header(BEARER token).
  - Click on your Resources in your API Gateway and choose your lambda function and under Method Request you will be able to assign your created authorizer under (Settings -> Authorization).

Comment: can you provide details or a link regarding idToken as i was using CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider from AWS SDK for Android and it didn't have that field.